# file_get_html not works - HTTP request failed! Request denied Error

Tags: php, file, dom, get

Im trying to get div content from some other website using file_get_html().
When i connect to the server i got following error.

**Warning: file_get_contents(http://www.example.com/view/204284808.php): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 999 Request denied**

Now my question is how can i fix this issue or the the blocked DOM operations from server?

Can i get it?

```
<?php
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');

$html = file_get_html('https://www.example.com/view/204284808.php');

$html = $html->find('div[class=lartz]', 0);

echo $html;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you have to enable allow_url_fopen in your php.ini config.
Or, you can use cUrl.